# Play youtube video with Youtube API v3

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube-api

I start just now using the Youtube API v3 for C# (WPF) and I have some problem to understand how it works. I already read the examples in the [Google Developers API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads), but I don't find a simple example to play a video. 
I use this code to retrieve the list of videos matching the query string:

```
YouTubeService yt = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() 
{ ApiKey = "MyAPIKey" });


var searchListRequest = yt.Search.List("snippet");
            
//searchListRequest.ChannelId = "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID";
searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
searchListRequest.MaxResults = 10;

var searchListResult = searchListRequest.Execute();
foreach (var item in searchListResult.Items)
{
     Console.WriteLine("ID:" + item.Id.VideoId);
               
     Console.WriteLine("snippet:" + item.Snippet.Title);
     lista.Items.Add(item.Snippet.Title);

}
```

With this code I get the list of 10 result from Youtube.
I read in other thread to use `WebService`, but I don't find the video in the list result.
***How can I access the video?*** Have I to do the research with other methods?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# but try using a webBrowser control to play the video. This [tutorial](http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/) will help you to call JavaScript from C# and C# from JavaScript you can now embed and extend web applications into native applications with ease. Also another [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/27121/stream-youtube-videos-in-wpf) shows how to play streaming videos from YouTube in WPF. Hope this help